# How to correctly error out in JSON parsing with Data.Aeson

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, applicative, aeson

My type and correponding FromJSON implementation as listed below.

The `nonEmpty` turns a `List` into a `Maybe NonEmpty` and I'm trying to correctly deal with the case where the `List` is indeed empty and I have to abort the parsing. This parsing is actually done inside of [`parseJsonBody`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.8/docs/Yesod-Core-Json.html#v:parseJsonBody), which means I don't want to `error "foo"` my way out of it, but I want to return `mzero` (or whatever else will do the trick, `mzero` is the only thing I've stumbled upon so far) so that the handler correctly returns a 400 instead of crashing with a 500.

The approach below compiles, but as far as I can tell is pretty much equals to `error` or some other form of exception throwing inside of the parseJSON. If I return `mzero` however (e.g. with `<*> mzero` instead of that line), it fails nicely as intended.

```
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as NE
data GSAnswer = GSAnswer { gsAnswerQuestionId :: Int
                         , gsAnswerResponses :: NE.NonEmpty GSResponse
                         } deriving (Show, Eq)


instance FromJSON GSAnswer where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    GSAnswer <$> o .: "question-id"
             -- how do I return mzero here based on NE.nonEmpty?
             -- this will throw an exception right now on an empty list
             <*> fmap (fromMaybe (fail "foo") . NE.nonEmpty) (o .: "responses")
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

One option would be to somehow pattern match on the result of `fmap NE.nonEmpty (o .: "responses")`, but I can't quite figure out what the pattern would be there: doesn't look like Parser has any constructors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, you need a `Parser [a] -> Parser NE.NonEmpty` transformer, which is relatively easy:

```
-- toNonEmptyP :: Parser [a] -> Parser NE.NonEmtpy
toNonEmptyP p = fmap NE.nonEmpty p >>= maybe mzero return
```

We map `NE.nonEmpty` on our regular list parser, which gives us `Parser (Maybe NE.NonEmpty)`. We then inspect the `Maybe` with `maybe` and either use `mzero` if it was `Nothing`, or `return` the parsed value back to the parsing context. Your `FromJSON` instance then boils down to

```
instance FromJSON GSAnswer where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    GSAnswer <$> o .: "question-id"
             <*> toNonEmptyP (o .: "responses")
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

You can use `fail msg` instead of `mzero` to provide a custom error message, as `fail :: String -> Parser a` doesn't bottom out.

Comment: Seems to do the trick, thank you. Any suggestions regarding how to add a specific error message to a Parser failure? Right now the reported error message is "mzero", it'd be neat if I could pass my own error message there for why Parser had to abort.

Comment: Have you tried `fail "msg"` instead of `mzero` in the transformer? I'm currently not at my PC, but I can check later.

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thank you, I altered the above to:

    toNonEmptyP :: String -> Parser [a] -> Parser (NE.NonEmpty a)
    toNonEmptyP msg p = fmap NE.nonEmpty p >>= maybe (fail msg) return